# Angular 8 render component without extra wrapper element in the DOM

Tags: angular, components, selector, wrapper

I am trying to split my presentational component to multiple components.
When I use selector like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss']
})
```

it adds a wrapper "app-video" element as a parent of my component and it breaks my styling. Because I expect to have DOM structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div>myComponentContent</div>
</div>
```

and instead I get this:

```
<div class="container">
   <app-video>
     <div>myComponentContent</div>
   </app-video>
</div>
```

I don't need this  wrapper element. Because I expect that my component must be the direct child of my container.

one way that solves this problem is that I use either a class selector or the selector like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-video]',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss']
})
```

Which works fine, but tslint complains about it because it is considered as a bad practice according to angular style guides:

https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-03

Can anyone tell me the best and valid way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "break" your styling ? The css from your component ?

Comment: I edited the main post. Please have a look

Comment: But you have a global style affecting yout parent AND your child ?

Comment: Yes. Parent element is a flex container and it decides how my flex items should be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using view encapsulation: none, on your component
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: I think you misunderstood my case. My styling breaks because of extra element in the dom. I expect to have a structure like this: <div>mycomponent</div> and instead I get <div><app-video>mycomponent</app-video></div> this breaks my styling because I expect that mycomponent should be the direct child of the div

Comment: So it looks like this div element is unneeded ,  remove it and uddate selectors , adding new dom element is how it suppose to work

Answer (score 0):

It is better to follow best practices. So try to add style into global style to keep your selector `selector: 'app-video'`:

```
div app-video {
    background: lightorange;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

As an alternative, you can try to remove selectors something like this:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}


ngOnInit() {
    let yourNativeElement: HTMLElement = this.el.nativeElement,
        parentElement: HTMLElement = nativeElement.parentElement;
    // get all children and move them out of the element
    while (nativeElement.firstChild) {
        parentElement.insertBefore(nativeElement.firstChild, nativeElement);
    }
    // remove the empty element(the host)
    parentElement.removeChild(nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: Is not there a better solution than this? I am forced to use one extra dom element which I dont need. It does not feel right

Comment: I dont understand. My main objective was to split my big component to small components and that is why I created separate component. And what you tell me is that I should put it back where it was.

Comment: @Dito so you can remove manually your selector from HTML. Please, see my updated answer