# Angular 7+: Render Component Without Container HTML Element (Messes up Bootstrap Styling)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-components

Pretty straightforward problem I'm having, I think. Bootstrap requires the HTML for its grid system to work properly. Here's a very simplified general example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Nicely-formatted!
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, if I pull out that interior part into a separate Angular component, it adds a wrapper container that throws off Bootstrap's styling and messes up the layout entirely:

Source HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <app-my-component></app-my-component>
</div>
```

My Component HTML:

```
<div class="col">
  Nicely-formatted!
</div>
```

**NOTE**: I cannot move the `col` div outside the component, nor move the `row` inside the component. The rows belong to the parent component (and differ a lot/etc.), and the cols to the child component instances.

The resulting HTML when rendered (and now it unfortunately lies, as it is no longer nicely-formatted):

```
<div class="row">
  <app-my-component>
    <div class="col">
      Nicely-formatted!
    </div>
  </app-my-component>
</div>
```

Is there a way to instruct Angular to *not* render the `<app-my-component>` tag? I'd rather it just inline the HTML directly, which would solve my problem.

[This similar question received no love, after most comments/answers addressed the wrong thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59008962). Help solve our collective issue! :) (And if rendering Angular components without the wrapper tag is impossible, I'm open to suggestions!)

I would rather not wedge in hacky styles to go against the Bootstrap conventional styling, or remove the sub-components (I re-use them and repeating their code in the HTML would be quite the pain).

Suggestions about how to rearrange the HTML are appreciated, but this is a symptom of a larger issue I run into often anyway: Being able to turn off the rendering of the component HTML in general.

Comment: Did you try adding the row class to mycomponent?

Comment: @JohnPeters It doesn't belong in my-component. I'll make an edit to clarify that, for my purposes, it makes no sense to move the `row` inside the child component or to move the `col` outside the child component. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: One other note in your custom component css you can use the :root. Pseudo selector for styling

Answer (score 0):

I did find a way to keep the Bootstrap layout without sacrificing my separation of parent/child components. A pretty simple one I believe.

Instead of using a `<div>` for the `row` class, I put that directly on my component HTML, and no adjustments are otherwise needed:

```
<app-my-component class="row"></app-my-component>
```

The final output HTML reads as follows (and the contents once more speak the truth):

```
<app-my-component class="row">
  <div class="col">
    Nicely-formatted!
  </div>
</app-my-component>
```

The solution boils down to "use the component as the container class for Bootstrap instead of a div tag." It lets me keep the `row` (and other logic) correctly outside the child component while also letting me keep what I put inside the child component on the inside.

As far as I can tell, Angular tags will display `inline` by default (as opposed to `block` for `<div>` tags). Applying the `row` class, of course, changes it to `flex` just like when applied to other container tags, and it seems to otherwise-behave just like a `<div class="row">` (a good thing).

For anyone looking for "I need direct CSS hierarchy for the layout to work", this should help you out.